# Understanding lexographical sorting

Tags: sorting, ascii

I am trying to understand lexicographical sorting, I know for a fact that capital letters come before lower case ones. Let say the number 3 has an ASCII value of [53] and the number 10 = [49 48] does this mean the number 10 is before 3?

Thank you

Comment: The *string* `'10'` will sort before the *string* `'3'`.

Comment: perfect, thank you.